# spring xd source moodule does not processing files parallelly

Tags: spring-xd

I am working on Spring XD M7 version. I have created a steam source | processor | sink. I have total 5 files in my source folder.When my stream deployed, it is processing sequentially where I have 3 nodes spring xd cluster with redis configured.

My input source is local file system in xd-admin node. Is there any way to configure spring xd to process my files parallelly.

If I use partition strategy, I can tell to specific files to go to the specific containers. But, this is not my requirement.

I have 5 files in my source dir, I want to process files parallelly since I have 3 nodes spring xd cluster with redis configured.

Please help me on this.

Thanks,
-Suyodha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the count for the source module to 1 (default) and for the next module(s) to whatever level of parallelism you want; setting it to 0 will deploy it on all available containers. See the [reference manual about deployment manifests](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.0.0.RC1/reference/html/#deployment-manifest).